# need some help in android game developing?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a game for android and it's like a match game it looks like that:

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/96718770.png/]

the game work perfectly but the problem is the size of the cards " the clowns in the picture "didn't change I've tried everything from changing the size of the image to change the size of the image view, the xml file is a Tablelayout and each row table contain something in the first row there is the image view that will display the card and this is the xml code

```
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/Row01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
 >
  <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/ImageView1" 
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"

    ></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: you shouldn't be using static values, use wrap_content and use min_width

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, you should probably avoid static values when designing your layouts as much as possible so they remain scalable from tiny-phone to mega-tablet.

This is a common problem for people who develop android and in this case it's probably a screen density issue.  I would suggest making three different sized sets of your clown icon and putting them in the low, medium, and high resolution image folders in your "res" folder.  That's the reason they have those folders, if your application is scalable across screen sizes the system will pick the appropriate resolution image from the folders when you make a call on that resource.  You can also modify how the system chooses density in the manifest I believe.